# Open Collector config ULN2003

Tags: bjt, open-collector

Are open collector configurations like those found in [ULN2003](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/uln2003a.pdf?ts=1681601642864&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FULN2003A%253Futm_source%253Dgoogle%2526utm_medium%253Dcpc%2526utm_campaign%253Dapp-psil-null-prodfolderdynamic-cpc-pf-google-wwe_int%2526utm_content%253Dprodfolddynamic%2526ds_k%253DDYNAMIC%2BSEARCH%2BADS%2526DCM%253Dyes%2526gclid%253DEAIaIQobChMI3Jzeioat_gIVQxh9Ch0F-g1OEAAYASAAEgJGDPD_BwE%2526gclsrc%253Daw.ds) always in saturation (when Sufficient Base voltage is applied)? Can they never go into the active region?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The manufacturer's intended application is saturated switch, with input pins driven by digital logic. All its data sheet specs for ULN2003 point to switch-type service.
**But** every pin brought to the external world invites alternate use. Can the ULN2003 operate in analog domain?
 *Of course* - but this domain is at the users risk. You'll have to characterize much of its "linear" operating envelope yourself and expect little supplier support for such service (unless you're willing to buy very large quantities).
Although the data sheet shows an internal schematic with base resistor of 2.7k, 7.2k, 3k, these resistors likely have poor tolerance from one device to another.

---

For example, a data sheet suggests that a substrate diode should not be used to carry current. If collector-emitter voltage should go negative, causing this diode to conduct, the manufacturer can claim violation of service. No reason is given for this particular operating-envelope caution.

There may be other operating-envelope cautions that can cause problems that never occur in the conventional switching service that the manufacturer just doesn't mention.

Comment: So as long as i use a microcontroller to power the IC, I'm guaranteed to observe the IC operate in Cutoff or Saturation. Is this correct to say?

Comment: **Cutoff -> Saturation** is the intended operating envelope: the manufacturer suggests: *[...] allowing operation directly with TTL or CMOS operating at supply voltages of 5 V or 3.3 V*. This would include a microcontroller GPIO. A darlington's saturation can't be expected to compete with a single-transistor saturation - this is carefully specified in the data sheet graphs.

Answer (score 2):

ULN2003 is simply a darlington array, each channel consisting of two transistors and a few resistors in a darlington configuration.

Surely they can go into the linear/active region.
Just look up [the datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/uln2001.pdf) and you'll find the following schematic:

[image: ULN2003 Schematic]

There is also a graph showing exactly what goes on in the active region.
[image: Figure 15]

Although, the ULN2003 cannot be considered a representative of all open collector devices. There are many with TTL, CMOS or similar type of inputs that can only be on or off.

Comment: well the main motive behind me asking this was to identify whether my reasoning for the darlington pair being in saturation was right or wrong. It'd be of great help if you could confirm it https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/662980/uln2003-low-side-switch-electrical-characteristics